# How do I make the winforms controls resize with the window?

Tags: c#, winforms, window

So, when I have a form, and I resize it, the controls just get hidden "behind" the form, i guess. I want the controls to resize with the form. How can I do this?

Comment: dock,anchor.....but aside from that you should also set the form minimum size so the user cant resize beyond a certain size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Anchors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8y52cxte%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [Docks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1w8z0xh4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). In addition, controls like a TableLayoutPanel can also support you when creating a layout.

Answer (score 2):

see in MSDN [Windows Forms Layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951306.aspx)

also [Dock, Anchor and Fluid layouts in Windows Forms Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466129/dock-anchor-and-fluid-layouts-in-windows-forms-applications)