# How to adjust the form size when padding of a certain control is changed

Tags: c#, winforms

hi is there a way to adjust form size when padding of a certain control is changed? this is ti prevent controls to overlap the when changed the padding on run time is there a way to do it? or property to set? Currently Using Winforms

Comment: It is not clear, what technology you use: WPF, WinForms, ASP.NET, Silverlight...?

Comment: SOrry i forgot to indicate above im currently using Winforms

Answer (score 1):

Better use the layout controls effectively you can avoid the overlapping of controls.

Refer [for WPF Container controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514628(v=vs.90).aspx) and [anchoring and docking properties for Win forms](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/designtechniques/article.php/c13585/Changing-Layout-Dynamically-in-Windows-Forms.htm)

Answer (score 1):

There are controls in Windows Forms that enable automatic layout. When using theese controls, you can change e.g. margin of a button and the layout will be automatically adjusted so that controls do not overlap. 
See **FlowLayoutPanel** and **TableLayoutPanel**

See this answer: [Dock, Anchor and Fluid layouts in Windows Forms Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466129/dock-anchor-and-fluid-layouts-in-windows-forms-applications)

or the second link in Vasi's answer.

When you need a custom behavior, you will have to program it or combine various controls like Dock panels, anchors, fluid and table layouts. Generally those tasks are easier using WPF, in WinForms it is more difficult.

To change the size of the entire Form I think you need to set it explicitly, there is no automatic Form resize feature:

```
this.Size = new Size(800, 600);
```